# Call C++ function in DLL from WP8.1 RT or WP8.1 Silverlight

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

Currently I'm working on both WP8.1 RT and WP8.1 Silverlight project.

Both [WP8.1 RT] and [WP8.1 Silverlight] could call native function from DLL, right?

Does the c++ DLL project type has something to do with [WP8.1 RT] and [WP8.1 Silverlight]?

I'm sort of confused,

There are 5 types of dll project in VS2013 for WindowsPhone

```
DLL(Windows Phone 8.0)             <- WP8.0 SL
DLL(Windows Phone)                 <- WP8.1 RT
DLL(Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1) <- WP8.1 SL
Windows Runtime Component(Windows Phone 8.0) <- WP8.0 SL Runtime component
Windows Runtime Component(Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1)
```

Thanks for the answer from Soonts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference between DLL and Windows Runtime Component is the API they expose.

DLL exports functions callable from C++ code, or from C# in WP 8.1 (before 8.1 the [DllImport] attribute was broken).

Windows Runtime Components doesn’t export functions, instead they expose COM-like objects + .NET-like type information. That objects can be used from another C++/CX projects, or from .NET (even from SL on WP 8.0). In addition, they can consume other WRT components (both your own and system-provided).

Internally, they both can contain classic C++ code, calls to allowed subset of WinAPI, and calls to other unmanaged DLLs in your xap/appx package.

The difference between WP Store and WP SL is the API it is allowed to use. There’re some APIs that are only present in Silverlight, however all API available to WP Store is accessible to WP SL.

So in short, if you need to support WP 8.1, both Store and SL — choose “DLL (Windows Phone)” if you’re going to code classic C++ and expose C-style API, or “Windows Runtime Component (Windows Phone)” if you’re going to mix classic C++ and C++/CX, and expose object-oriented API.